# How to run a .php file on server always whenever any page in same project gets executed

Tags: php, servlets, servlet-filters

like in java we use filters which can act as global filter with annotation @WebFilter("/*") so I also want to do something same in PHP.So how can a .PHP file run whenever any page is run in same project?
My work is to analyse every request and response and other details of client whenever he/she hits the page...so need to run set of code always whenever user hits a page so how to configure that code without making changes in all webpages files of a single website(project).

Comment: include it? not really sure what your asking. how are you defining a 'project' in this case? and whats the file do exactly?

Comment: As far as I understand your question you are looking for php auto append/prepend: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-automatically-append-prepend/

Comment: Probably you can use a framework such as codeigniter that has routing features

Comment: my code will be added to an existing project so I can't use my framework,I want something similar to filters in java which is global by the help of annotation or XML configuration

Comment: maybe you can make some kind of dispatcher, using `.htaccess` file to redirect all requests to certain page (filter) which in turn analyze or do whatever you need, then redirect the request back to the original destination ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try include a call to PHP script in all pages, or into a generic page.
You need call this command "require".

Look here: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.require.php

Simple example:

```
<?php
require('somefile.php');
?>
```

But if you need run always this, why you can try configure a CRON on linux or task Scheduler in Windows. This a better choice.

Comment: My work is to analyse every request and response and other details of client whenever he/she hits the page...so need to run set of code always whenever user hits a page so how to configure that code without making changes in all webpages files of a single website(project).

Comment: hello, sorry but i see this question just now...
Go on, this realy simple. make a call your script to page with require.
Maybe call this in your index.php, every reload page, you can get all informations, and you can make different tests before, and get data analyses all time.

Try insert require or require_once <?php 
require_once ('/script.php');
require ('/script.php');

The diference between requires is that case you script  dont locate script.php, the system stop, or show just error.